# Autotools: create a 32-bit and 64-bit library with a single makefile?

Tags: linux, autotools

I am trying to convert a project to autotools. My project consists of a program and a library. The library is *not* linked with the program. Instead, the library will be linked with *other* programs to communicate with my program. My program is 64-bit, but I need both a 32-bit and a 64-bit library to make sure it can be used by any program. I can't figure out how to do this - it seems like autotools only supports one host architecture for the entire package.

I've tried setting the -m32 flag to get a 32-bit library, but that doesn't work because the linker tries to link with /usr/lib instead of /usr/lib32. Even if I add /usr/lib32 to the linker flags, I still get errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/../../../../lib/crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/crtbeginS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/crtendS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/../../../../lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

So I guess this isn't the right way to do it. I could create a separate package for the library of course, but I want to avoid that. Is it possible to keep everything in one package?

The solution doesn't have to be cross-platform, this program is linux-only.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distros that I know of that support 64-bit have 2 versions of each lib package: a 32-bit and a 64-bit.   Since autotools supports only one host architecture, it would be easiest to do two builds.